# Guides for dealing with Unicode in PHP5?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, unicode, utf-8

Hey everybody. I'm developing a new site (php5/mySQL) and am looking to finally get on the Unicode bandwagon. I'll admit to knowing next to absolutely nothing about supporting Unicode at the moment, but I'm hoping to resolve that with your help.

After desperately flexing my tiny, pathetic excuses for Googlefu-muscles, and scouring over each page that looked promising to my Unicode-newbie eyes, I have come to the conclusion that, while not entirely supported, my precious language of choice (PHP for those that have forgotten) has made at least a half-assed attempt at managing the foreign beast (and from what else I see, succeeding?). I have also come to the conclusion that

```
<php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

is a great place to start and that I should be looking into supporting UTF-8 since I have plenty of space on my (shared, for the moment) hosting.

However, I'm not sure what this strange functionality known as mb_* means or how to incorporate it into functions such as strlen() and . . . to be honest at this point I don't know what other functionality (that I can't live without) is affected.

So I've come to you SO-ites in search of enlightenment and possibly straightening out my confused (where Unicode is concerned!) brain. I really want to support it but I need serious help.

P.S.: Does Unicode affect mysql_real_escape_string() or any other XSS prevention/security measures? I need to stay on top of this as well!

Thanks ahead of time.

- Adding Javascript into the mix, since I'll be using a mix of pure and jQuery and no knowing about Unicode support + this language. ;)

Comment: +1 for asking the questions that too few ask. Unicode is something every programmer should understand.

Comment: Not to mention PHP and unicode isn't very straightforward

Comment: Focus on understanding character sets, character encodings, a little binary. This is pretty language independent stuff. Once you start to get a grip on it, you'll realize php's "shortcomings" aren't really a big deal.

Comment: @chris: I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure I understand. I'm looking for supporting Unicode in PHP (specifically through UTF-8 since like I said I'm not worried about space but don't need UTF-32). I know it requires "odd" things to work properly, but I'm not sure what all "odd" defines, like what mb_* 'replaces' (thank you etranger).

Comment: My bad. The purpose of my comment was that I feel the most important thing in order to support unicode is to understand the things I listed, and not so much php specifics of unicode support.

Comment: It's fine, I understand what and why you said that and it's appreciated. However PHP's "shortcomings" are pretty severe if I don't know how to handle support properly in my primary language. Which is why I'm hoping someone can respond with even more info like whether or not security is more/less compromised by supporting it, which 'normal' PHP built-in functions need to be "changed" and to what, like etranger mentioned, the "UTF-8 without BOM" (that I didn't know about). :)

Comment: That is a temporary deficiency in your knowledge, not a fault of php. Other languages don't magically make unicode work as if we lived in a world of ascii. Lots of bad answers being given here already...good luck.

Comment: Yes, a temporary deficiency in knowledge about how PHP treats Unicode, which I already stated was the case about a hundred times. However as far as I know no one has ever stated that code languages "make Unicode work". What we've stated is that certain functions don't work well with Unicode and support for it is different than with ASCII - which is what PHP < 6 handles by default. Single-byte characters. So I have to disagree. Lots of HELPFUL answers have been given here already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Welcome onboard utf8 :)
2. You should simply use mb_* functions *in
   place* of your traditional str*
   functions
3. MySQL and its API has
   long and well been supporting utf8,
   the only requirement that you *use*
   encoding when saving data and
   connecting. google for 'SET NAMES
   utf8'
4. Note the 'u' modifier for
   preg_* functions that tells them to
   use unicode mode.

Comment: PS Your source code files should be utf8 WITHOUT BOM, because it makes output before PHP even starts and causes painfully strange "Headers already sent" issues.

Comment: 1) Thank you very much. I'm happy to be here. :) 2) Is there any "cheat sheet" type place that lists them, or a place that shows how-to? (PHP's manual erm, well, pretty much lost me). 3) I did find that much out at least, and how to store in UTF-8. 4) '/u', right? 5) I use Notepad++ running in Wine, so to respond to your response I select "UTF-8 without BOM" and that should solve the source code file? -Also, I'm sorry this is a mess of a reply. I'm kind of new to responding here and don't know if there's anyway to newline since pressing the Enter key seems to send my comments along their way.

Comment: 2) sorry, never had any, original php documentation was good enough for me 4) yup! 5) yes, sounds right. BTW, I'm not even sure that comments on SO support line breaks at all :)

Comment: Hm. So mb_* is a replacement for any byte (or character)-specific function in that it supports multi-byte characters (Unicode!), right? This leaves my question of security and whether anything changes there, like mysql_real_escape_string() (probably doesn't) or htmlentities() (does it?). And, of course, if there's anything else that I haven't discovered that I need to know.

Comment: you are correct about mb_*; mb stands for mbstring, a multibyte strings extension. mysql_real_escape_string() uses the same encoding as database connection, so as long as you connect as utf8, you're safe. as far as htmlentities, can't really confirm reliability, as it has had issues with cyrillics (which was my reason behind using utf8 in the first place)

Comment: Don't use htmlentities()...use htmlspecialchars().  As long as your encoding (charset), is set correctly in your page the client will display utf-8 characters fine.  Using htmlentities() will just output an entity that your browser probably won't understand.

Comment: @etranger: Thanks for that. :) @Yzmir: I heard that using htmlspecialchars() was "better" anyway, so that's no issue there. @both: Since you two seem really knowledgeable about this, can I ask about Javascript Unicode support, in particular jQuery, and if I need to do anything "special" there? I know I originally made this for php5/mysql, but there will also be some Javascript (jQuery) and I want to make sure I have all my bases covered.

Comment: nothing special for jquery really, the only thing I found disturbing is how php's json_encode() deals with non-ascii characters, converting them to \uXXXX notation, which is not nice. this affects json, but not javascript directly.

Comment: I'll be pulling the latest "tweet" from Twitter and storing it in the database, but since this is more backend I don't suppose I need to encode it in UTF-8? Or will this cause an issue when spitting it out elsewhere? This instance is really the only time I'll be using json in conjunction with PHP.

Comment: if twitter returns utf8, no more need to convert it of course (i'm not familiar with the API). upon saving, you can try outputting the saved data as json, if that is what you need, and see for yourself. \uXXXX is valid unicode for javascript, just hard to debug, so nothing major here AFAICS.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to just give a list of links, but these are some that I found helpful:

- http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet
- http://www.herongyang.com/PHP/non_ascii_string.html
- http://www.herongyang.com/PHP/non_ascii_form.html
- http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets
- http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8
- http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html

Answer (score -1):

When working with unicode:

- use **`<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />`** on top of your page when you output
- right after you connect to your database use the sql query: **`mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");`**
- make sure all tables and required fields have a collation type of: **'utf8_unicode_ci'**

Comment: I was under the impression that a combination of proper doctype and html tag did a better job than the meta. Can someone clarify that for me? And as far as connecting to the database, I thought that if the page itself was encoded UTF-8 and the database was UTF-8, all was well there?

Comment: I have used the above combination to make things work. I also found the 'mysql_query("set names 'utf8'")' necessary. As for proper doctype vs meta question do consult an expert.

Comment: I don't know who did it, but it wasn't me.